# Getting a file from GCP Storage with Node.is

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to create a REST API (an endpoint) for getting a file from GCP Storage.

The function is:

```
    async getFileFromGCP(some inputs): Promise<file: any> { return file;}
```

As you can see it returns a file. A file already uploaded on GCP Storage.

The result of REST API will be a decrypted file. How can I do that?

Comment: Add more details about what you tried to do to get a file from GCP Storage and what you means by `decrypted file`.

Comment: A file in GCP Storage is encrypted, when I get it by Rest Api it should be decrepted.

Comment: And how is this decryption process related to GCP Storage?

Comment: It is my question.

Comment: Your title says about getting file from GCP storage as well as your phrase: `I'm trying to create a REST API (an endpoint) for getting a file from GCP Storage`

Comment: So you decide either you ask how to get a file content from GCP Storage or how to decrypt this file content

Comment: Actually both of them, because when file uploaded in GCP, it is encrypted too. I need endpoint that get that file from GCP and that file must be decrypted too. I writ the body of the method that i created to fetch file from GCP, I need the code inside body of that function which get a file from GCP Storage, and decrypt the file also.

Answer (score 1):

Google offers official APIs for interacting with Google Cloud via Node.js, amongst other languages.
Furthermore it is not possible to retrieve encrypted files from Google Cloud Storage, unless you are using customer-managed encryption keys, the decryption happens transparently when you attempt to fetch the files.

As such I would simply recommend you to use the official function call by Google to retrieve a file:
`await storage.bucket("bucketName").file("filename").download();`

Please take a look at this example file from the documentation for more information:
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/downloadFile.js